# Apache Arrow c++ gdb extension "There is no member named status_."

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Hi I am building a simple apache arrow cpp program to start learning the library. I have setup clion with cmake and clang++. I build an array like this from tutorial code:

```
    arrow::Int64Builder builder;
    builder.Append(1);
    builder.Append(2);
    builder.Append(3);
    builder.AppendNull();
    builder.Append(5);
    builder.Append(6);
    builder.Append(7);
    builder.Append(8);

    auto maybe_array = builder.Finish();
    auto is_ok = maybe_array.ok();
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> array = *maybe_array;
```

now when I put a breakpoint directly after and try to print the array I get the following error:

```
(gdb) print array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/clion/bin/gdb/renderers/default/printers.py", line 158, in lookup
    delegate = gdb.default_visualizer(dereferenced)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/arrow/gdb/gdb_arrow.py", line 2422, in arrow_pretty_print
    return ArrayPrinter(val)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/arrow/gdb/gdb_arrow.py", line 1820, in __init__
    data = deref(val['data_'])
                 ~~~^^^^^^^^^
gdb.error: There is no member named data_.
$1 = std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> (use count 2, weak count 0) = {get() = 0x555555595630}
(gdb) print maybe_array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/arrow/gdb/gdb_arrow.py", line 2155, in to_string
    state_ptr = self.val['status_']['state_']
                ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
gdb.error: There is no member named status_.
$2 = 
(gdb) 
(gdb) print is_ok
$3 = true
```

can somebody explain me what went wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of libarrow are you using here? I can't reproduce what you're seeing. From your output, I see that CLion sets up its own printers so I wonder if CLion and Arrow's gdb printers are conflicting here. Can you try outside of CLion just as a test? https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/gdb.html might be helpful.